# Should reposync download repodata?

Tags: rhel, repository

I am using reposync on an RHN repo.  It downloads the RPMs just fine, but doesn't download repodata.  I know I can run createrepo, but I'd like to keep group install info.

Is this normal behavior?  If so, is there some other way I can copy the repodata?

Comment: From http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Software_Management_Guide/ch08s04.html : 

"The important thing is to maintain regularly synchronized the local mirror with the master repository running every hour reposync and createrepo. It is important to note that the groups file is not downloaded by reposync. Use wget or curl to download it."

This answers half the question.

Answer (score 1):

From http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Software_Management_Guide/ch08s04.html

> The important thing is to maintain regularly synchronized the local
>   mirror with the master repository running every hour reposync and
>   createrepo. It is important to note that the groups file is not
>   downloaded by reposync. Use wget or curl to download it.

I dont know how to use wget or curl to get files from RHN, but here is another way that should work:

```
reposync -p /home/user/reposync/all/ -r rhel-x86_64-workstation-6 -l
yum clean all
yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=rhel-x86_64-workstation-6 makecache
cp -f /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6Workstation/rhel-x86_64-workstation-6/*.gz /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6Workstation/rhel-x86_64-workstation-6/*.xml /home/user/reposync/all/rhel-x86-64/getPackage/repodata/
```

Note that 'yum clean all' is probably excessive. I think yum clean metadata is sufficient but I havent checked.

Comment: for groups download, just download the /repodata/comps.xml file to your repository